# Selecting first element in Group by object Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, datatable

I have the following table and I want to get the specidic Amount per loan_ID  that corresponds to the earliest observation with greater than or equal to 10 dpd per month.

```
Loan_ID date    dpd Amount
1   1/1/2017    1   55
1   1/2/2017    2   100
1   1/3/2017    3   5000
1   1/4/2017    5   6000
1   1/5/2017    10  50000
1   1/6/2017    15  50001
1   1/9/2017    31  50004
1   1/10/2017   55  50005
1   1/11/2017   59  50006
1   1/12/2017   65  50007
1   1/13/2017   70  80000
1   1/20/2017   85  900000
1   1/29/2017   92  100000
1   1/30/2017   93  10000
2   1/1/2017    0   522
2   1/2/2017    8   5444
2   1/3/2017    12  8784
2   1/6/2017    15  6221
2   1/12/2017   18  2220
2   1/13/2017   20  177
2   1/29/2017   35  5151
2   1/30/2017   60  40000
2   1/31/2017   61  5500
```

The expected output:

```
Loan_ID Month Amount
1       1      50000
2       1      8784
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also clarify your question.  Do you want a `sum()` or a specific row?

Comment: Updated it. I need the amount at the specific row (the first row where dpd >= 10) per month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Loan_ID", date_trunc('month', "date"))  
  "Loan_ID", 
  date_trunc('month', "date")::date as month, 
  "Amount"
FROM 
  loans
WHERE
  dpd >= 10
ORDER BY
  "Loan_ID", 
  date_trunc('month', "date"),
  "date"
;
```

Returns:

| Loan_ID | month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-01-01 | 50000 |
| 2 | 2017-01-01 | 8784 |

You can find test case in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6b63773c212e3940a7a04a5da428c801)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . if you want the amount per month *and* the first date that matches the condition, then you want conditional aggregation:

```
select loan_id, date_trunc('month', date) as mon,
       sum(dpd),
       min(case when dpd >= 10 then dpd end) as first_dpd_10
from t
group by load_id, mon;
```

Edit:  Based on your comment, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (loan_id, date_trunc('month', date)) t.*
       min(case when dpd >= 10 then dpd end) as first_dpd_10
from t
where dpd >= 10
order by load_id, date_trunc('month', date), date
```

Comment: here instead of min dpd, I need the amount corresponding to the row where dpd >= 10 for the first time per loan, per month

Comment: @gunel . . . So much for being first.